# Parentheses and Typecasting

Tags: c, gcc, casting, parentheses

I'm working on an embedded controller, with a few different non-standard types defined, EG:

```
uint8 = unsigned char
sint16 = int
```

If I need to typecast from `uint8` to `sint16`, where should i use my parentheses?

```
uint8 u8_My_Var = 255;
sint16 s16_New_Var = 0;

s16_New_Var = ((sint16)u8_My_Var + 1); //or
s16_New_Var = ((sint16)(u8_My_Var) + 1); //or
s16_New_Var = ((sint16)(u8_My_Var + 1)); //or
s16_New_Var = (((sint16)(u8_My_Var)) + 1);
```

I would normally use `(((sint16)(u8_My_Var)) + 1)`, however I started wondering about the 'scope' of the type cast.

Comment: First, second, and fourth are the same; the third is dangerously dirfferent, it does the computation in unsigned 8 bit (wraps at 256) and then casts.

Answer (score 1):

Type casts take precedence over addition, so all but the third line (`s16_New_Var = ((sint16)(u8_My_Var + 1));`) are equivalent. However, if you want to perform the cast after the addition, this is the one you need.

Note that the outermost parentheses are redundant in all cases, since type casts also take precededence over assignments.